# Scala: what is the best way to add elements to a Map with a collection as value?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Let's consider this:

```
val m: Map[String, List[String]] = Map ( "foo" -> List("one", "two", "three"))
```

How can I add a value to `m` like `("foo" -> "four")` to get `Map ( "foo" -> List("one", "two", "three", "four"))`?

Comment: If you can use different type, then this may better suit your needs: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is one trivial approach:

```
m + ("foo" -> (m("foo") :+"four"))
```

A safer approach as suggested in the comments, is by using `getOrElse` when you try accessing `m("foo")`.

```
m + ("foo" -> (m.getOrElse("foo", Nil) :+ "four"))
```

Comment: Or a safe variant if you don't know whether a value already exists: `m + ("foo" -> (m.getOrElse("foo", Nil) :+ "four"))`

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but there exists some similar semigroup operation in scalaz:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

Map ("foo" -> List("one", "two", "three")) |+| Map("foo" -> List("four"))
```

Comment: I think if you wrap the "four" element with List you don't need Scalaz. You can just use breakOut.